# Why does my attempt to access a MariaDB in my Java program get give me an 'access denied' exception even tho my password is right?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I'm writing a Java program that queries an SQL database, and pulls out my query, to see if a username and password exist in my database. My code is:

My code is:

```
public UserInfo getUserExists(final String userEmail) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if (!isBlank(userEmail)) {
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;

        try{
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to DB...");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://10.0.0.0:3306/mydb","myusername", "mypassword");

            System.out.println("Connected to DB successfully");
            System.out.println("querying if user is valid");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT IF (EXISTS(select user_email, user_pass, meta_value from myorg_users left join myorg_usermeta on ( myorg_users.id = myorg_usermeta.user_id) where meta_value LIKE '%\"administrator\"%' and meta_key=\"myorg_capabilities\" AND user_email="+userEmail+"),1,0) AS result;");
            int result = 0;
            System.out.println(rs);

            while(rs.next()){
                result = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("result"));
                System.out.println("result is " + result);
            }
            conn.close();
            if(result == 1){
                UserInfo SYSTEM_USER = new UserInfo.Builder(UserInfo.Username.valueOf("SYSTEM_USER")).withFirstName("System").withLastName("User").withEmail(userEmail).withUserId("sample").build();
                System.out.println(SYSTEM_USER);
                return SYSTEM_USER;
            }

        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        throw new AuthenticationException("user does not exists in system");
    }
    System.out.println("executed new user exists");
    return null;
}
```

However, when I run my API, I get this, and I KNOW the password/username are correct -

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'10.%' to database 'mydb'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1036)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.intuit.wasabi.authentication.impl.DefaultAuthentication.getUserExists(DefaultAuthentication.java:168)
    at com.intuit.wasabi.api.AuthenticationResource.getUserExists(AuthenticationResource.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at com.intuit.autumn.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'10.%' to database 'mydb'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:787)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:713)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:402)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1032)
    ... 59 more
```

What is going on? I've run this query in the DB and it works in MariaDB. Why can't I achieve what I need in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well java aside, are you ssure you going to access your db on 10.0.0.0 ? I would make an educated guess your MariaDB is configured to listen on loopback interface (127.0.0.1) so if your MariaDB isnt configured to listen an other interface you would get a connection refused kinda case. So i would start to check this if you are sure you can do it in the phpmyadmin (i guess you use that and it might be accessed over localhost?). and 10.0.0.0 shouldnt be a possible ip.

Comment: I only put 10.0.0.0 so I wouldn't be putting the actual IP address the server with the DB is on

Comment: Again I would check if your mariaDB config is working with an interface other then the loopback and if so does your firewall accept connection to the port specified

Comment: how can I find the loopback address? I did so `\s;` in mySQL, and got this: Connection id:          13944870
Current database:       mydb
Current user:           myusername@10.10.20.2
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MySQL
...
Connection:             10.10.55.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306

Comment: in the reply above, I changed numbers of the IP addresses. The one my java code has is the equivalent of 10.10.55.1 in my previous reply

Comment: Loopback is usually 127.0.0.1 but if your db isn't running on your local machine and you can connect to it without java it might not be the problem.

Comment: Oh and I don't know if this is a thing here since I don't do java but is there a mariaDB driver ? Usually it's only MySQL since mariaDB is just a different form of MySQL after Oracle got there hands on mysql. So you might check that out too

Comment: so what do I need to do? Do I need to set up an nginx server on my local machine? I feel like now I'm lost. Is there no way I can do this with 10.10.55.1?

Comment: you can see in the function that I have `Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")` tho IDK if that's enough

Comment: No why should you do that ? Where is your db running? Is the bind- address in  my.cnf set and what's the value?

Comment: Do you use a mariaDB package in your code? I guess you need to import some stuff to use mariaDB related functions

Comment: But again I think the Problem ist with the config of mariaDB not with the java code, check your my.cnf and if your IP is not the IP mariaDB binds to you should adjust that and restart mariaDB

Comment: my db is on 10.10.55.1; I did find a bind address in the my.cnf file of 127.0.0.1. In terms of MariaDB stuff in my code, I do have the jdbc in my project's pom.xml file tho I import java.sql.* into the .java file

Comment: she there is the problem if its set to 127.0.0.1 it means mariadb is just listening to local connection on the machine where mariadb is running on so if your java code runs on a diffrent machine it wont work with the 10.x.y.z ip ! if your code runs on the same machine as the db use jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb or jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydb. If you want to connect from some other location you need to set the bind-address to the value of the ip address you would connect to the db machine from some place inside yoour net work (so a 10.x.y.z value)